# SSRS - exclude hidden values from sum

Tags: oracle, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder

I did not hide the entire rows.  I hid just the duplicated values in one column and I need to sum that same column, excluding the hidden values. Thank you very much.

The field having duplicated values that I wanted to hide is SpaceArea This is how I hid the duplicated values from rows on the SpaceArea column:

```
=IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value),True, False)
```

Then I need to SUM all the SpaceArea excluding the hidden values.

Once I tried to use the same Show/Hide logic to the Sum expression as per another post of yours, I got an error message. This is what I tried:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!SpaceID.Value = Previous(Fields!SpaceID.Value), Nothing, Fields!SpaceArea.Value))
```

==> then I got this error message:

> previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Comment: Can you edit the SQL behind this at all?

Comment: Yes, I can.  However the users would like to see the other fields on that row.  They do not want to hide the entire row, just that field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` in your SQL to highlight the duplicates.

`row_number() over (partition by SpaceID order by (select null)) as [RowNumber]`

This will give you an arbitrary numbering to the duplicate rows.

Then in SSRS you can use..

`sum(iif(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!SpaceArea.Value, Nothing))` to only sum the first instance of each duplicate.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking time to respond.  I did try your suggestion, but I got an error message at the (select null), the error message said "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Actually I think I got it.  It worked.  Thank you so very much for your help :)